# ODE on Sphere. Determining its angular change

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the ODE system
$$
x_1'=x_2,~~~~~x_2'=-ax_2-bx_1+x_3,~~~~~x_3'=0.
$$

I would like to know its behaviour on the unit sphere $S^2$, i.e. know the change of radius and angle.

So I can write it in polar coordinates and just ignore $x_3$?

[image]

Comment: There are a couple of things I don't understand: 1. What do you mean by "change of radius and angle"? 2. The vector field $(x_{2}, -ax_{2} - bx_{1} + x_{3}, 0)$ isn't generally tangent to the sphere. Is the idea that the sphere gets deformed (by a _spatial_ flow), and you want to quantify the deformation of the sphere somehow?

Comment: I mean the following: I am searching for $\varphi'$ where $\varphi$ is the angle in polar coordinates. Just as for example with the very easy 2d-example that $x_1'=-x_2, x_2'=x_1$ where we get that $r'=0$ and $\varphi'=1$ for the polar coordinates.

Comment: The ODE you have written down does not define a rigid motion of space, and does not rotate the sphere.

Comment: Hm, do not understand, sorry.

Comment: So $\varphi'=0$ for the sphere, right? What is $r'$?

Comment: I hope the diagram I posted clarifies my previous comment. :) The vector field $x_{1}' = -x_{2}$, $x_{2}' = x_{1}$, $x_{3}' = 0$ rotates the sphere about the $x_{3}$-axis, and does arise just as you say by ignoring $x_{3}$. Are you trying to write down a vector field that rotates the sphere about an arbitrary axis or something along those lines?

Comment: I am just trying to understand what the ode does with half-lines that start in the centre resp. what happens with points on the sphere by the ode.

Comment: I. e. what it does on the projective space $P^2$.

Comment: Cannot see that from your picture. If I have a line in the projective space (and identify opposite points on the unit sphere) I think that the ODE does something with this line but I do not see what. The picture has again to be a line ... but which line.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\Neg}{\phantom{-}}\newcommand{\Vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}$**Edit** (based on clarifications in the comments): In matrix form, your system of ODEs is
$$
\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
x_{1}' \\
x_{2}' \\
x_{3}' \\
\end{array}\right]
= \left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
\Neg 0 & \Neg 1 & 0 \\
-b & -a & 1 \\
\Neg 0 & \Neg 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
x_{1} \\
x_{2} \\
x_{3} \\
\end{array}\right]
$$
The standard analytic approach is to diagonalize the coefficient matrix $A$ (or put it into Jordan canonical form if it isn't diagonalizable). The solutions are
$$
\Vec{x}(t) = \exp(tA)\Vec{x}_{0}.
$$

Qualitatively, the eigenspaces of $A$ are fixed directions, i.e., fixed points of the linear action on the projective plane; generalized eigenspaces are invariant sets of the action; and the relative sizes of eigenvalues tell whether a given fixed point or invariant set is attracting or repelling.

---

**Edit II** (based on further comments): The eigenvalues of $A$ are $0$ and $\frac{1}{2}(-a \pm \sqrt{a^{2} - 4b})$. If these are all real, the corresponding eigenvectors are $(1, 0, b)$ and $(1, \lambda, 0)$.

For instance, if $b < 0 < a$, then
$$
\frac{-a - \sqrt{a^{2} - 4b}}{2} < 0 < \frac{-a + \sqrt{a^{2} - 4b}}{2}.
$$
The first eigenspace is repelling, the second is a saddle, the third is attracting.

The new plot indicates the flow of your system when $a = 2$ and $b = -4$. The curve you call $C$ is in red. By happy coincidence, the curves align nicely with the curves in your diagram.

In an eigenbasis, $\exp(tA)$ is the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries
$$
e^{\lambda_{1}t} < e^{\lambda_{2}t} < e^{\lambda_{3}t}.
$$
As $t \to \infty$, every point of the sphere (or projective plane) approaches the $\lambda_{3}$ eigenspace. It should be clear geometrically why asking about the change of radius and angle isn't really adequate language to capture the qualitative behavior of your ODE. :)

[image: The flow on the sphere for $a = 2$ and $b = -4$]

---

Not an answer, but too long for a comment.

The plot below shows the vector field (scaled overall by $\tfrac{1}{4}$ to make the arrows easier to see) corresponding to the system
$$
x_{1}' = x_{2},\quad
x_{2}' = -ax_{2} - bx_{1} + x_{3},\quad
x_{3}' = 0
$$
for $a = 0.4$ and $b = 0.2$. The field itself is blue, the tangential component to the sphere is green, and the normal component is red.

[image: A linear vector field on the unit sphere decomposed into tangential and normal components]

Comment: I know that it has two saddle points, two attracting points and two repelling points, the picture I add in my questions shows one of each

Comment: but I do not know how the motion looks like when I start anywhere on the sphere.

Comment: Or let me put it otherwise. We have two stable subspaces (the stable subspace and the centre subspace) and one unstable subspace. Let these be spans of the eigenvectors $X_1$ (unstable), $X_2$ and $X_3$. Now set $C:=\text{span}\left\{X_2,X_3\right\}\cap S^2$ and let $V$ be a neighborhood of $C$. Now assume $z\notin V$. Why does this imply that it is driven to some neighborhood of $\text{span}\left\{X_1\right\}\cap S^2$? And where is it on my picture?

Comment: (for example: where is C in my picture?)

Comment: Just me being curious: can you share a gist on GitHub for plotting these wonderful pictures, please? :)

Comment: @Evgeny: The [ePiX](http://mathcs.holycross.edu/~ahwang/epix/ePiX.html) source files are here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/237bf905d99bdd73f1b5 :)

Comment: Wow, cool, thanks! I was looking for different visualization tools (with more attention to Python tools) but this one went under my radar :)