# Any "meaningful" PDE defined to $\mathbb{S}^m$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, spheres

Is there any differential equations which their *co-domains* are $n$-spheres, in particular the $2$-sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$, that represents certain physical phenomena or has applications in non-math field(s)? Google-ing "DE on sphere" gives me the differential equations with the "sphere" on the *domain* instead.

ODEs with spherical co-domains (like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1517570/) although I don't get its applications, and/or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3249869/)) are also welcomed but I would prefer partial ones, as simple as possible, at this moment. Thanks a lot.

Comment: For example, given any surface $M$ in $\mathbb R^3$, the [Gauss map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_map) is a map $N : M \to \mathbb S^2$, and constraints on the curvatures of $M$ can be written down in terms of derivatives of $N$.

Answer (score 1):

Try searching "liquid crystals", "harmonic map", "wave map", "heat map", "Schrödinger map". Each of these keywords points to some manifold-valued differential equation.